# Bulk account creation from text file

Tags: bash, account, creation

I have the following script, it reads from users.txt the first and second fields and uses them to generate the username and password and creates the accounts for each line. the problem is that the script is only creating accounts for the first 2 lines and not for the rest

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/knoppix/users.txt
USERSH=/bin/bash


while IFS=":" read GECOS USRGRP ; do

groupadd -f $USRGRP



USERNM="u$(cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 6| head -n 1)"
USERPW=$(cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6| head -n 1)


useradd $USERNM -p $USERPW -g $USRGRP -c "$GECOS,$USRGRP" -d $HOME/$USERNM -s $USERSH -m

ACCNT=$(grep $USRNM /etc/passwd)
echo "${tgrn}Account creation successful!${tr}"
echo "$ACCNT"
echo "Credentials"
echo "${tred}Username:${tr} $USERNM ${tred}Password:${tr} $USERPW"
echo
done < $FILE
```

Comment: Time for a new book, _Why Jo:hnny can't have a Unix account_. (Obligatory [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/) reference here.)

Comment: Put this before your `groupadd` command and post the output: `echo "[$GECOS] [$USRGRP]"; continue`

Comment: root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# ./accounts
[Jose David Garcia] [Student]
[Yasin Ahmed] [Student]
[Utah King] [Student]
[Michael Jackson] [Student]

is not even reading the last line (stack overflow:staff

Comment: Sounds like there's something fishy about the file.

Comment: Thats right!, i changed the ownergroup and ownership of the file to root and now it operates smoothly, it creates all accounts.

how did u know there was something fishy about the file

Comment: The script looked fine so the next thing to verify was the input to the script.

Comment: If you're going to accept an answer please don't destroy your question. It makes the answer meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read GECOS USRGRP; do

    # your groupadd and useradd commands here

done < /home/knoppix/users.txt
```

Comment: Hi sorry the script above was not updated, im using while IFS. now the problem is that it only adds the first two accounts from the text file

Comment: You need to post your actual script if you want us to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $file; do
# make the account

done
rm $file
touch $file
```